Does put-call parity hold for physically settled options?
In Chapter 13 (Some Wrinkles of Option Markets) of Dynamic Hedging (pages 222-223), N. N. Taleb introduces the concept of expiration pin risk and follows by making the statement:

$\color{red}{\mathcal{S}}:$ Put/Call parity does not hold for non-cash-settled listed options (both European and American).

When viewed without context, this may seem surprising since it contradicts classical theory (European options). However, as Taleb explains, the deviation from theory is caused by information asymmetry between the short seller and the counterparty. This arises due to operational constraints within brokerage firms, such as processing delays for exercises and assignments, which prevent immediate notification of assignment status.
He attempts at making the aforementioned concept more robust by providing the following scenario:

A market on a listed exchange is closing at 100 exactly. The trader is short the 100 calls, long 100 puts and long the underlying future—what a text book would call a perfect hedge (the so-called conversion). The trader does not know whether to exercise or not. Should he exercise all his puts and deliver the futures, he would hope that the calls get entirely abandoned. Should he abandon the puts, he would wish to see all his calls exercised so he can deliver his futures. The party on the other side will be in the same quandary. What makes matters even more complicated is that a closing price on a future is not a real indication as to where the market will be at the times of exercise. The future closing does not usually terminate the option: There is a gap of a few hours in which information can still hit the markets with operators guessing the general effect of such information without more precision.
In the preceding example, assume that the future closes at 101 but that after the close news of a government scandal hits the market. The operator may wonder what to do with the 100 puts, officially out-of-the-money. He knows with some certainty that the market would be lower if it were open to trade. His risks are that he may abandon the puts and not be assigned on the calls with the market opening markedly lower. The other risks are that he may exercise the puts and still be assigned on his calls, with the market unchanged if the news is subsequently denied after the deadline. Often some of the counterparties with a large open interest can manipulate the markets and turn the uncertainty in their favor, as when they become in possession of a large sell order and decide to exercise options deemed out-of-the-money.

Unfortunately, the example Taleb mentions, led me into despair and confusion :D
Question 1: Let $t_{exercise}$ denote the time the trader decides to exercise the puts and with $T$ the actual maturity of the option (after the future contract delivery), then $T \leq t_{exercise} \lessapprox T + 1.5 \text{ hours}^{**}$. Let
$t_{news}$ denote the time the news hit the market and $t_{extended}$ the time after hour trading ends, with $T \leq \{t_{news},\,\,t_{extended}\}$. There are a couple of cases I am thinking of:
$1.$ If $t_{news} < \{t_{exercise}, \,\,t_{extended}\}$ then $\color{red}{\mathcal{S}}$ makes sense to me as you are effectively introducing some optionality in the option.
$2.$ If $t_{exercise} \leq t_{news} < t_{extended}$ then information on the news only has effect on the stock price and therefore I do not see why $\color{red}{\mathcal{S}}$  should be true.
$3.$ If $t_{exercise} \leq t_{extended} < t_{news}$ then information on the news does not have any effect on the stock price move or exercise decision, so $\color{red}{\mathcal{S}}$ does not make sense to me.
Both $2$ and $3$ are introducing extra "time-value" without having any actual value as the stock price does not move or does not have any effect on the decision. Am I reading into this in the wrong way?
Furthermore, he continues by stating:

The only markets where a conversion or a reversal is a pure arbitrage is where the underlying is a cash-settled future that expires at the same time as the option. Examples: Eurodollars, Euromarks, Pibor (the quarterly options), SP500 (quarterly¹).
Warning: Traders, like poets, often give the same designation to two different items. "Pin risk" is also used to refer to the P/L swing at the barrier for a portfolio containing barrier options.

Question 2: How is the assertion "The only markets where a conversion or a reversal is a pure arbitrage is where the underlying is a cash-settled future that expires at the same time as the option" true?

(**) 1.5 hours was conservative estimate (see this)
